# Unable to detect page cache due to possible loopback request

Tags: wordpress, cache

We have installed cache plugin(WP Rocket) on our website.

However, in my WordPress website health check, there is an error:

**Unable to detect page cache due to possible loopback request problem. Please verify that the loopback request test is passing. Error: Not Found (Code: http_404)**

Then I check the loopback test and it is passed:

**Your site can perform loopback requests**

I search online and find this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75683729/unable-to-detect-page-cache-due-to-possible-loopback-request-problem-please-ver

But it does not provide solution as well.

So how to fix this issue?

**It seems that health check is trying to accessing some URLs to perform the tests but get 404 errors. So which URLs is it trying to access? Maybe I can check and fix them.**

Answer (score 0):

According to [WP Rocket FAQ](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1728-site-health-check#your-site-could-not-complete-a-loopback-request)

> A loopback request is a call that the server makes to itself'.

Check your own server access logs for any 404 errors.